# How can i redirect to another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

is there any ways to redirect to another page..?
i used to "window.location.href = downlinkPage"

i wanted to access the downlinkPage and then get the pages file informations

like fileLink and fileName

is there any ways to access the downlLinkPage and get info from files??

Comment: read this and the comments too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.assign()` is one way to do it. For example,

`window.location.assign("http://example.com");`

redirects to example.com.

If you want to erase the current page from history, replace the `assign` with `replace`.

Comment: is there any way to below the codes..? i used your recommended..but it doesn't access the page

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use  `location.href`
>
> If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`

For example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

but the code after won't get to execute and the whole page and its context, all will be released.
You need to download the page , parse and extract the information you want from it.
Using jQuery you can simply :

```
$.get("downlinkPage", function(data, status){
   $($.parseHTML(data)).filter('your desire query');
});
```